# Magento - How to write breadcrumbs with the H1

Tags: magento, title, breadcrumbs

On cms pages (http://trustedsurgery.com/cat-scratch/declawing-cats) the breadcrumb is pulling in the title of the page.

How can I change the breadcrumb so that the H1 is displayed and not the title?

On product pages, the H1 is being pulled in (http://trustedsurgery.com/cat-scratching-products/2-pack-deal-cat-nail-caps-8-12-months-pd25.html)

Any advice is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the breadcrumbs div is present in that page layout.
I think the cms pages have 2columns layout . chk the 2columns layout file having the breadcrumbs div. If it's not present means plz add this code where you need the breadcrumbs

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
```